# Find files with find-dired sorting by date and by size

Tags: sorting, find-dired

I often use `find-dired` and `find-named-dired`.
But I wanted to get the results sorted by date and by size.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

After doing some googling for the Linux `find` parameters and looking at the `find-dired` function, I came with these two functions that seem to work.

Not sure if this is the optimal way, but at least they have the effect I desired:

```
(defun find-dired-by-date (dir args)
  (interactive (list (read-directory-name "Run find in directory: " nil "" t)
             (read-string "Run find (with args): " find-args
                  '(find-args-history . 1))))
  ;; Set to this value in order to get a find sorted by date
  (setq find-ls-option '("-exec ls -lt {} + | cut -d ' ' -f5-" . "-lt"))
  (find-dired dir args)
  (setq find-ls-option '("-ls" . "-dilsb")))

(defun find-dired-by-size (dir args)
  (interactive (list (read-directory-name "Run find in directory: " nil "" t)
             (read-string "Run find (with args): " find-args
                  '(find-args-history . 1))))
  ;; Set to this one to get it sorted by size
  (setq find-ls-option '("-exec ls -lSr {} + | cut -d ' ' -f5-" . "-lSr"))
  (find-dired dir args)
  (setq find-ls-option '("-ls" . "-dilsb")))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use library [**`find-dired+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) then you can do the date part using command **`find-time-dired`**:

> **`find-time-dired`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> `(find-time-dired DIR MIN-TIME MAX-TIME &optional DEPTH-LIMITS
>   EXCLUDED-PATHS)`
>
> Find files in directory `DIR` newer or older than a timestamp.
>
> The output is shown in a Dired buffer.
>
> `MIN-TIME` is a format-time string parsable by `parse-time-string`, such
>    as `"2014-12-25 23:59:00"`.  Only files newer than this are shown.
>    If `MIN-TIME` is `nil` or a string matching regexp `"^\s-*$"`, there is
>    no lower time limit.
>
> `MAX-TIME` is also a format-time string parsable by `parse-time-string`.
>    Only files older than this time are shown.
>    If `MAX-TIME` is `nil` or a string matching regexp `"^\s-*$"`, the upper
>    time limit is the current system time.
>
> Optional arg `DEPTH-LIMITS` is a list `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)` of the
>    minimum and maximum depths.  If `nil`, search directory tree under `DIR`.
>
> Optional arg `EXCLUDED-PATHS` is a list of strings that match paths to
>    exclude from the search.  If `nil`, search all directories.
>
> If args `DEPTH-LIMITS` and `EXCLUDED-PATHS` are both non-`nil` then the
>   command run is essentially the following:
>
> ```
> find . -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH
>        \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
>        -prune -o \( -TIME-SWITCH -SINCE-MIN -TIME-SWITCH +SINCE-MAX \)
>        LS-SWITCHES
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.
> - `TIME-SWITCH` is `find-diredp-time-prefix` concatenated with `"min"`.
> - `SINCE-MIN` is the elapsed time since MIN-TIME in minutes.
> - `SINCE-MAX` is the elapsed time since MAX-TIME in minutes.
> - `LS-SWITCHES` is `(car find-ls-option)`.

User option **`find-diredp-time-prefix`** determines whether to use the time of the last modification of a file (its contents) or the time of the last change of a file's status.

@nephewtom shows how to use `find-dired` to find by size (and time).